# urllib2.urlopen - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, urllib, python-webbrowser

```
import urllib2
response=urllib2.urlopen("http://yts.ag")
print response.info()
response.close()
```

The above program shows the following error in python 2.7.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "url_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib2
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 111, in <module>
    from urllib import (unwrap, unquote, splittype, splithost, quote,
  File "D:\Python\Python Test codes\urllib.py", line 4, in <module>
    "Names and Addresses, URIs, URLs, URNs, URCs", at
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

I tried replacing the library file but did not help.

Comment: Editing the question to become completely different defeats the purpose of answering it and makes this thread useless to future readers. Open a new question if you have to. I did a rollback to your original question. If you have further queries, first close this question and post a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your traceback, it shows that one of your file in your cwd is called `urllib.py`, you can’t call it that because `urllib2` needs to import a module that is also named `urllib`. It’s currently trying to import your file located `D:\Python\Python Test codes\urllib.py`.

To fix the error, you just need to rename that file.

**Note**: you should never mess around changing the library’s source code. It *will* mess the library up.

Comment: The above error is shown now

Comment: @A3L2J Can you really expect to have people solve all your issues? The main subject of your question has been answered. Close this and open a new one.

Comment: Please do not post another question in place of your existing one, ask a new question. But, I think it’s pretty self explanatory, you cannot access the webpage with the current setup as the website refuse to connect, you can try using `https://yts.ag` or try setting your own user agent

Answer (score 1):

Look at these 2 lines in your traceback:

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 111, in <module>
    from urllib import (unwrap, unquote, splittype, splithost, quote,

 File "D:\Python\Python Test codes\urllib.py", line 4, in <module>
    "Names and Addresses, URIs, URLs, URNs, URCs", at
```

It's a clear naming conflict between one of your files and one of the inbuilt modules `urllib2` calls. It's confusing your `urllib.py` with its inbuilt one. All you need to do is **rename your file**, and it should work.

**Note**: Never name your files similar to to the libraries you use, otherwise you'll run into some "unexpected" errors.

Comment: Now the above error is shown

Comment: ummm.... I see no difference...??